# Angular how to preserve a user_id across different views

Tags: angular

I have a table wrapped in a form in Angular, what I want to be able to do is: the user clicks on there selected product and that has an id_number associated with it, this id_number needs to be able to be shared across views once its selected as the api gets information based on this number? Is it best to create a service for this? then inject that service into each view? Code for table is:

**html:**

```html
    <form [formGroup]="assetForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover mb-10">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Sev</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let incident of data">
                <td>
                    <label class="form-radio">
                        <input type="radio" name="id_number" [value]="asset.id_number" formControlName="id_number" <i class="form-icon"></i>{{incident.number}}
                    </label></td>
                <td>{{incident.sev}}</td>
                <td>{{incident.phone}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!Form.valid" type="submit">Select</button>
</form>
```

**ts file:**

```js
    ngOnInit() {
    this.assetForm = new FormGroup({
        id_number: new FormControl(''),
    });
}

onSubmit() {
    if (this.assetForm.invalid) {
        this.assetForm.setErrors({
            ...this.assetForm.errors,
            'required': true
        });
        return;
    }
    this.uploading = true;
    this.service.postlist(this.assetForm.value).subscribe((response: any) => {
        console.log(response); //On success response
    }, (errorResponse: any) => {
        console.log(errorResponse); //On unsuccessful response
        this.error = true;
        this.uploading = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Look at the location bar of your browser. See that number "55180593"? That's the ID of your question. When clicking on the question in the list of questions of the StackOverflow homepage, you navigate to a page which has the ID of that question in the URL. The same thing should be done with Angular. And that way, if you refresh the page or bookmark it, you go back to this question immediately. https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Yes... but what would be the best way to do this...

Comment: Reading the documentation I linked to is the first step. Trying something is the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to create a service, then set the value in it and in the needed view/component, get the value from the service. If you are using the service approach, and at some point, if the page got refreshed due to any reason, you can have a simple check for the ID whether it exists in the service or not & redirect to the needed view with ease if needed. I would not recommend using local storage for the same.

Like, create a service say S. You have components A, B & C. In component A, set the needed id in the service S and that id value can be accessed in B & C with injecting the services in B & C.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutesModule } from './app.routes';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AComponent } from './acomponent.ts';
import { BComponent } from './bcomponent.ts';
import { CComponent } from './ccomponent.ts';
import { CustomService } from './custom.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AComponent,
    BComponent,
    CComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutesModule,
  ],
  providers: [
   CustomService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**custom.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomService {

   user_id: any;
   fetchDataURL = "http://localhost:3000/api/some-link";

   // Set data
   setUserId(id) {
       this.user_id = id;
   }

   // Fetch data
   getUserId() {
       return this.user_id;
   }

   // Fetch data which contains "user_id"
   fetchData(): Observable<any> {
       return this._http.get<any>(this.fetchDataURL, httpOptions)
       .pipe(
          retry(1),
          catchError(this.handleError)
       );
   }

   // Error handler - you can customize this accordingly 
   handleError(error) {
     let errorMessage = '';
     if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
       // client-side error
       errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
     } else {
       // server-side error
       errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
     }
     return throwError(errorMessage);
   }
}
```

**a.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { CustomService } from './custom-service-location';

@Component({
  selector: 'component-a',
  templateUrl: './a.component.html'
})

export class AComponent  implements OnInit {

    fetchedData: any;
    constructor(private customService: CustomService) {}

    ngOninit() {
        this.getData();
    }


    // Fetch data
    getData() {
        this.customService.getData()
          .subscribe((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            this.fechedData = data;
            this.customService.setUserId(data.user_id); // Passing the user id to service
          },
          (error) => {
              // logic to handle error accordingly
          });
    }
}
```

**b.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { CustomService } from './custom-service-location';

@Component({
  selector: 'component-b',
  templateUrl: './b.component.html'
})

export class BComponent  implements OnInit {

    user_id: any;
    constructor(private customService: CustomService, private router: Router) {}

    ngOninit() {
        this.getData();
    }


    // Fetch user id from service
    getUserData(id) {
        this.customService.getUserId()
          .subscribe((data) => {
            this.user_id = data.user_id;
            if(this.user_id == null) {
                this.router.navigate(['/component-a-route']) // If the id is lost on some page refresh, redirect back to the needed page
            }
          },
          (error) => {
              // logic to handle error accordingly
          });
    }


    someOtherFunction() {
      // some other function with some other logic
    }
}
```

As you can see above, there is the main "app" module, two components a & b and a service file. In component A, you call the function fetchData which return "user_id" in it(suppose), you set the user_id in the custom service using "setUserId()" method, then you are able to fetch it in the component b using "getUserId()" method.

I hope the above makes things clear & it helps.

Comment: @Sole, I have updated the answer with the sample codes.